# How to update the deployed version?

Tags: gmail-addons

I have gone through the process of listing our Gmail Add-On in the G Suite Marketplace and that went great but now I want to update it but am having some issues.

**I can update the Gmail Add-On by doing the following:**

1. Create a new Deployment Version in the App Script Editor and copy
   the DeploymentID
2. Go to the Project and open the Apps Marketplace SDK
3. Under the Configuration tab for Gmail Add-On Extension pasting the
   new ID
4. Save

However only I can do this but when anyone else tries the save is greyed out and they get a message in red about having to submit a request to publish but they can make changes to the Publish tab. Working with Google they pointed me to https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/manage-addons#update_published_add-on_code but I can't get past step 5.

Anyone else come across this issue and able to resolve it?